# How to broadcast same message to all TextField on same view in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Each time I add a new field I have to send the same message as existing fields from a central method. Is there a way to be more generic and send that message for once to all fields on the view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the view's `subviews` array.

```
for(UIView* view in [myView subviews]){
    [view myMessage];
}
```

Comment: too easy for you so what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573874/how-to-broadcast-same-message-to-all-objects-of-same-name-suffix-on-same-view-in :)

Comment: Answer Code:  for(UIView* view in [myView subviews]){
    if([view class] == [UILabel class]){
        // it's a UILabel
    }
    if([view class] == [UITextField class]){
        // it's a UITextField
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

For example i want to send removeFromSuperview message to all its subviews, you can do that with single statement

```
[[myScrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: Answer code:for(UIView* view in [myView subviews]){
    if([view class] == [UILabel class]){
        // it's a UILabel
    }
    if([view class] == [UITextField class]){
        // it's a UITextField
    }
}