# How to broadcast same message to all objects of same name suffix on same view in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

It's easy enough to send message to object of same type:
[How to broadcast same message to all TextField on same view in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573552/how-to-broadcast-same-message-to-all-textfield-on-same-view-in-iphone-sdk/9573609#9573609)

What if I want to do the same but to to all objects of same name suffix (for example uilabelFirstName and uitextfieldFirstName) ?

Comment: Might be easier to use tags...

Comment: Objective-C objects don't have names.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done using `subviews` (or any other alternate pointer to an object)

When you are in that subview loop as in that other answer,

```
for(UIView* view in [myView subviews]){
    // my reference to "view" here  <---
}
```

You have a pointer to the *object*, but there's no way to get the names of pointers *to* an object.

You COULD, however, get the classes of each object, as it looks like your example names are attempting:

```
for(UIView* view in [myView subviews]){
    if([view class] == [UILabel class]){
        // it's a UILabel
    }
    if([view class] == [UITextField class]){
        // it's a UITextField
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but I'm not interested by class type so does it mean what I want is plain impossible ? I would be so upset I thought Objective C was exceptionally dynamic language.

Comment: @user310291 -- It's quite dynamic -- you can write code to do whatever you want -- so long as Apple allows it.

Comment: Since there's no way to convert the pointer name to a string, you'll have to use a different method. It's definitely dynamic...how many other languages lets you convert a string to an actual class?